# SAS: importing Excel document using libname

Tags: excel, import, sas

I'm busy looking through the SAS University edition tutorial. I'm trying to import data from a .xlsx file using the line below:

```
libname orionx server=pcfiles path="&path/sales.xlsx";
```

Here are some details I think may be relevant:
I'm running 32 bit Excel.
I **think** I have 32 bit SAS, but I'm not sure how to check.
I've run `proc setinit;` with the following result:

```
 1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 55         
 56         proc setinit;
 57         
 58         OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 Original site validation data
 Current version: 9.04.01M3P062415
 Site name:    'UNIVERSITY EDITION 2.3 9.4M3'.
 Site number:  70186327.
 CPU A: Model name='' model number='' serial='+2'.
 Expiration:   15JUN2017.
 Grace Period:  0 days (ending 15JUN2017).
 Warning Period: 45 days (ending 30JUL2017).
 System birthday:   09MAR2016.
 Operating System:   LIN X64 .
 Product expiration dates:
 ---Base SAS Software                                                                                    15JUN2017 (CPU A) 
 ---SAS/STAT                                                                                             15JUN2017 (CPU A) 
 ---SAS/ETS                                                                                              15JUN2017 (CPU A) 
 ---SAS/IML                                                                                              15JUN2017 (CPU A) 
 ---SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files                                                                     15JUN2017 (CPU A) 
 ---SAS/IML Studio                                                                                       15JUN2017 (CPU A) 
 ---SAS Workspace Server for Local Access                                                                15JUN2017 (CPU A) 
 ---SAS Workspace Server for Enterprise Access                                                           15JUN2017 (CPU A) 
 ---High Performance Suite                                                                               15JUN2017 (CPU A) 
 70
```

I think the relevant part is that SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files is active and expires only on 30June17. I think this means I should be able to access Excel files?

I'm running SAS through my browser via SAS Studio.

Many thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: University Edition is 64 bit.

Comment: There's a note in the training tutorials on how to access Excel files, with a specific note that if you're in SAS UE you can't do certain things. Not sure if you're using a tutorial or just practicing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is very easy.

You can't, because on the SAS University Edition there is no PC File Server, only the license include this product.

Fortunately you can use this code:

```
libname orionx XLSX "/folders/myfolders/sales.xlsx";
```

More info: http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2015/05/20/using-libname-xlsx-to-read-and-write-excel-files/

Comment: Technically you can use PC File Server to access files, but you need to externally download it and set it up. This is how people are getting around the restriction of accessing data bases. Using the PCFS you can access SQL Server or Oracle Server DB.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! When I follow the steps in the link, I get the following error: File WORK.XL.DATA does not exist. Any idea why this is? Thanks again!

Comment: Never mind, I was being silly. The location specification was incorrect so it wasn't finding the file. Changed this and it is working. Many thanks!